# How can I achieve java reflection in c#?

Tags: c#

**How can I achieve this java reflection in c#?**

Here is a method which returns any subclass of Class A.

```
abstract public Class<? extends A> getAClass();

class B extends A{}
class C extends A{}
```

the `getAClass()` method should return any of the class B or C.?

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with reflection.

Answer (score 4):

You need a [class constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
abstract public Class<T> getAClass() where T : A
```